# page.on('response') is not accessible in handlePageFunction // PuppeteerCrawler (Apify SDK)

Tags: puppeteer, apify

I try to get some data from the page.on('response') event. This data should be pushed into the dataset with pushData.

It seems that this events:

```
await page
    .on('response', response => {
        if (response.status() === 404) {
            responseErrors.push(new Object({
                status: response.status(),
                url: response.url()
            }))
        }
    })
    .on('pageerror', err => {
        if (err.message) {
            pageErrors.push(JSON.stringify(err.message))
        }
    })
    .on('console', message => {
        consoleErrors.push(new Object({
            type: message.type(),
            url: message.text()
        }))
    });
```

Have no response if they are used in handlePageFunction.

If i add them to the `gotoFunction` of PuppeteerCrawler i get results. The problem is that i cant push into the same dataset.

So what would be the right way to access this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't work in `handlePageFunction` because the page is already opened and responses have been processed. You have 2 options:

1. Use the `response` parameter on `handlePageFunction` https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/puppeteer-handle-page-inputs
2. Do what you did in the `gotoFunction` and instead of pushing to dataset, update `request.userData` and then read this in `handlePageFunction`, merge with your data and push to dataset.

Comment: Thanks again - got it working now. with the request userData.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [@Lukáš Křivka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898465/luk%C3%A1%C5%A1-k%C5%99ivka) i got the solution for me. Here is a code example:

userData Example:

```
const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
            requestQueue,
            launchPuppeteerOptions: {
                headless: true,
                ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
                // slowMo: 500,
            },
            maxRequestsPerCrawl: settings.maxurls,
            maxConcurrency: settings.maxcrawlers,
            gotoFunction: async ({
                page,
                request
            }) => {
                const responseErrors = [];
                const consoleErrors = [];
                const pageErrors = [];
                await page.authenticate({
                    username: settings.authenticate.username,
                    password: settings.authenticate.password
                });
                await page
                    .on('response', response => {
                        if (response.status() === 404) {
                            responseErrors.push(new Object({
                                status: response.status(),
                                url: response.url()
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                    .on('pageerror', err => {
                        console.log(err)
                        if (err.message) {
                            pageErrors.push(JSON.stringify(err.message))
                        }
                    })
                    .on('console', message => {
                        consoleErrors.push(new Object({
                            type: message.type(),
                            url: message.text()
                        }))
                    });
                request.userData.responseErrors = responseErrors;
                request.userData.pageErrors = pageErrors;
                request.userData.consoleErrors = consoleErrors;

                return page.goto(request.url, {
                    timeout: 120000
                });
            },
```

Access:

```
handlePageFunction: async ({
            request,
            response,
            page
        }) => {
            await page.waitFor(settings.waitForPageload);

            console.log(request.userData)
```